# Why getchar() works int these two cases differently?

Tags: c, character, getchar, nul

I am writing little program for encoding characters and I have a problem with reading NUL characters maybe also with another ones. My problem is that getchar in this code somehow ignores the NUL characters entered by CTRL + @ .

```
while ((numberOfRead < 40) && (character = getchar()) && (character != EOF) && (character != '\n')) { ... }
```

But this code works correctly and reads the NUL characters properly.

```
character = getchar();
while ((numberOfRead < 40) && (character != EOF) && (character != '\n')) {
    numberOfChars++;
    ...
    character = getchar();
}
```

What is the difference causing the problem? Thanks for any explanation of this behaviour. Code was tested on Windows 8.1, under gcc 4.7.1

Comment: This is why you should avoid assignment inside conditions, makes it very easy to write bugs.

Comment: ^^^ what @Lundin says.  I looks clever and cool, but doesn't actually work:(   Simple, one step at a time code, seemingly avoidable intermediate temp vars etc. result in working. or at least debuggable, code. Complex, compound boolean expressions result in posts to SO:(

Comment: I like the idea of using this assignment in the conditions due to many examples in the K&R, which I had read recently. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    while (... && (character = getchar()) && ...) ...
```

you use the value of `character` as truth value. When the read `character` is the null character with the value 0, this condition is false.

You can do something like:

```
    while (numberOfRead < 40
       && (character = getchar()) != EOF && character != '\n') { ... }
```

but I find your second variant with the `getchar` outside the condition more readable.

Comment: I had absolutely forgotten about the evaluating the assignment. :)

Comment: Yes, it's easy to miss in compound conditions. (That's why I prefer your second variant where it's clear where the `getchar` is called.)